AWS IAM Identity Center with Terraform
I have enabled AWS Identity Center in my org's management account and configured SCIM provisioning between AWS and my okta application. The users, groups on the okta application are pushed to AWS Identity Center. I have also configured another aws member account as a delegated admin account.
Now, I want to create aws permission set for the okta group that is pushed to AWS Identity Center. What are the terraform resources I should be using to create the permission set, assign it to the group to give access to multiple member aws accounts?
In what order should I chain the terraform resources?
I tried to read the terraform's official documentation but could not understand what resources I should be using for my use case.

What exactly is unclear from the docs?

@MarkoE after reading a few other blogs, my understanding is that

Create a permission set
Create a managed policy for the permission set
Assign the permission set to the okta group
Assign accounts to the group

Please correct me if I'm wrong. Also, since the okta groups are already synced on AWS, do I just pass the group name, id as a plain string? is there a dynamic way to pass the group id, name in code?

@MarkoE Another question, should I be deploying the permission set resources and account assignments to the management account or the delegated admin account?
